# Almacenar un campo de tipo timestamp en Spring boot

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Buen dia, Estoy haciendo un crud en Spring Boot
y en mi base de datos tengo un campo tipo Timestamp. Ahora, en Spring Boot al momento de guardar dicho campo desde un formulario en html me da error. Supongo
que es por el formato. Intente cambiarlo con un temporal para que me recibiera datos de tipo DATE pero me sigue dando error. Como puedo corregir este error?
Y como podría implementar un tipo de calendario
para no escribir la fecha manualmente sino tipo calendario?

Adjunto envio mi codigo, gracias.

Mi entidad ventas:

```
package com.springboot.siicoreapp.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="registro_ventas")
public class RegistroVenta implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_registro_venta;
    private String tipo_comprobante;
    private String num_comprobante;
    
     @Temporal(TemporalType.Date)
    private Timestamp fecha;
    private double subtotal;
    private double impuesto;
    private double total;
    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_tercero")
    private Tercero tercero;
    public Long getId_registro_venta() {
        return id_registro_venta;
    }
    public void setId_registro_venta(long id_registro_venta) {
        this.id_registro_venta = id_registro_venta;
    }
    public String getTipo_comprobante() {
        return tipo_comprobante;
    }
    public void setTipo_comprobante(String tipo_comprobante) {
        this.tipo_comprobante = tipo_comprobante;
    }
    public String getNum_comprobante() {
        return num_comprobante;
    }
    public void setNum_comprobante(String num_comprobante) {
        this.num_comprobante = num_comprobante;
    }
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
    public double getSubtotal() {
        return subtotal;
    }
    public void setSubtotal(double subtotal) {
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }
    public double getImpuesto() {
        return impuesto;
    }
    public void setImpuesto(double impuesto) {
        this.impuesto = impuesto;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Tercero getTercero() {
        return tercero;
    }
    public void setTercero(Tercero tercero) {
        this.tercero = tercero;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ventas [id_registro_venta=" + id_registro_venta + ", tipo_comprobante=" + tipo_comprobante
                + ", num_comprobante=" + num_comprobante + ", fecha=" + fecha + ", subtotal=" + subtotal + ", impuesto="
                + impuesto + ", total=" + total + ", tercero=" + tercero + "]";
    }
}
```

Ahora mi Controllador:

```
package com.springboot.siicoreapp.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.springboot.siicoreapp.models.entity.RegistroVenta;
import com.springboot.siicoreapp.models.service.IRegistroVentasService;
import com.springboot.siicoreapp.models.service.ITerceroService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ventas")
public class RegistroVentaController {
    
    @Autowired
    private IRegistroVentasService registroVentasService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ITerceroService terceroService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String listarTodos(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "SALES MODULE");
        model.addAttribute("rventas", registroVentasService.listarTodos());
        
        return "/views/registroVentas/listarRegVentas";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/createventa")
    public String crear(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Form: New Sale");
        model.addAttribute("rventas", new RegistroVenta());
        model.addAttribute("terceros", terceroService.listarTodos());
        
        return "/views/registroVentas/frmRegVentas";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveventa")
    public String guardar(@ModelAttribute RegistroVenta registroVenta, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        
        registroVentasService.guardar(registroVenta);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Record saved successfully");
        model.addAttribute("terceros", terceroService.listarTodos());
        
        return "redirect:/ventas/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id_registro_venta}")
    public String editar (@PathVariable ("id_registro_venta") Long idRegistroVenta, Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Form: Edit Sale");
        model.addAttribute("rventas", registroVentasService.buscarPorId(idRegistroVenta));
        model.addAttribute("terceros", terceroService.listarTodos());
        
        return "/views/registroVentas/frmRegVentas";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/delete/{id_registro_venta}")
    public String eliminar(@PathVariable("id_registro_venta")Long idRegistroVenta, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        
        registroVentasService.eliminar(idRegistroVenta);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("warning", "Record was delete");
        
        return "redirect:/ventas/";
    }
}
```

Adjunto mi vista de mi formualrio en html por si acaso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="plantilla/template :: head">

</head>
<body>
    <header th:replace="plantilla/template :: header" ></header>
    
    <div class="container"> 
    
        <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white" th:text="${titulo}"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
        
            <form th:action="@{/ventas/saveventa}" th:object="${rventas}" method ="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
            
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id_registro_venta}">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="id_tercero">THIRD PARTIES ID:</label> 
                <select th:field="*{tercero}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="id_tercero">
                <option th:each="ct:${terceros}"
                 th:value="${ct.id_tercero}"
                 th:text="${ct.id_tercero}"
                 />
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="tipo_comprobante">SALES SLIP TYPE:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{tipo_comprobante}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="tipo_comprobante"
                placeholder="type">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="num_comprobante">SALES SLIP NUMBER:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{num_comprobante}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="num_comprobante"
                placeholder="number">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="fecha">DATE:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{fecha}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="fecha"
                placeholder="date">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="subtotal">TOTAL PARCIAL:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{subtotal}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="subtotal"
                placeholder="total parcial">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="impuesto">TAX:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{impuesto}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="impuesto"
                placeholder="tax">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2" for="total">TOTAL:</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{total}" class="form-control form-control-sm col-md-6"  id="total"
                placeholder="total">
                <small></small> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-footer bg-dark">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Save"/>
            </div>
            
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <footer th:replace="plantilla/template :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se debe al paquete de donde importas la clase `java.security.Timestamp`, puedes utilizar `java.sql.Timestamp` y segun la version de spring boot te recomiendo utilizar `java.time.LocalDateTime (desde Hibernate 5.2.3)` o `java.time.LocalTime o java.time.LocalDate` según lo que necesites.